# Selenium Chorme Can't Add Cookie

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Im using Selenium to add Cookie to www.exmp.com but can't
this is a my code i using

```
string[] c_user = cook.Split('=');
browser.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie(c_user[0], c_user[1]));
```

Help me, error mess :  **unable to set cookie.**

Answer (score 0):

`Cookie name = new Cookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value");
driver.manage().addCookie(name);`

Can you try with this. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: not work bro, i try and have error unable to set cookie.